# Headless firefox does not exist after screenshot

Tags: firefox, headless

I want to use headless firefox to capture an image of a webpage on macos.

This is the command I executed: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com`

This is what I see in the terminal:

```
$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com
*** You are running in headless mode.
```

The problem is the firefox application does not terminated after the image is created. I can see a screenshot.png is already created in the directory I run the command, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

I have to kill the process by `Ctrl-C` at the end.

Is there any parameter I can pass to the executable to make it exit after the screen capture is done?

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have to manually quit firefox once the screenshot is done. This command should work:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com; pkill firefox
```

Explanation:

- ";" will run the first command followed by the second, regardless of success
- "pkill" will kill all currently running processes with "firefox" in the name

Comment: Alternatively, you can shove the command out into its own process with the '&' symbol:
`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com &`
then write a little while-loop with a short timeout that calls `ls | grep screenshot`, which will exit with code 1 if no files are found with the character pattern "screenshot", and exit with code 0 if something is found